# Can an iOS app file be updated while the app is still in review?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to update the file after initial submission of an iOS app to the app store?

We have a stable version of a new app ready to submit but wondering if we can post an update with new features even while the app is under review after few days of initial submission.  Or do we have to wait for the app to be approved first to submit an update?

Comment: this is on topic, per http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : " your question generally covers... software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Answer (score 43):

You can reject your first binary and upload the new one. Your position in the review queue will be reset. If you are worried about the release date more than your stability fixes you can just submit the update immediately after it is released to the app store.

[App Store Submission Tips](http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/appstoretips/)

> **Changing the Status of Your App -
>   “Developer Rejected” and “Developer
>   Removed From Sale”**
>
> Once you have
>   submitted your binary, iTunes Connect
>   allows you to manage and edit many
>   aspects of your application. However,
>   it’s important to understand the
>   impact making changes has on your
>   application, depending on its state.
>
> **Developer Rejected**
>
> If you need to
>   submit a new binary for your
>   application prior to it being reviewed
>   by the App Store Review Team, you can
>   change the status of your application
>   to Developer Rejected. To do so, log
>   in to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/), click on the
>   Manage Your Applications module, then
>   click the Reject Binary button from
>   the application summary view.
>
> Keep in mind that changing the status
>   of your application to Developer
>   Rejected while it is in the review
>   process removes your application from
>   the review queue. The review process
>   will start again from the beginning
>   once you resubmit your binary.

Comment: Update: In iTunes Connect, click on 'Manage Your Apps' -> <Your App> -> 'View Details' -> 'Binary Details' -> 'Reject This Binary'

Comment: After iTunes Connect redesign in Spring 2015, current method is to find the alert message at top of App's "Versions" page which mentions that you may remove the app from review, and click on that. This message sometimes takes an hour or so to appear after you submit the app for review.

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE**: as per the comment by Autonomy below, it looks like the policy has changed and you *can* now reject a binary when its status is **In Review**. I've left my original answer below for reference:

The answer to the question is NO. You cannot submit a new binary when then app is **In Review**. You can only reject your own app (Developer Rejected) whilst it is still in the **Waiting for Review** state, with the consequence that when you re-submit it will go to the back of the review queue. Once the app is **In Review** you have to wait for it to be accepted or rejected by Apple.

Comment: Not strictly true anymore, I rejected a binary that was 'In Review' recently.

Comment: Yep true, I'm able to reject my binary that was 'In Review' recently

Comment: does "remove this version from review." while my app is "In Review" also cause my position in the review queue will be reset?

Comment: @conman yes. Whenever you remove a binary from review your position in the queue is reset.

Comment: thanks @mluisbrown. Turns out after I rejected it and uploaded a new binary my app went back into "Review" within a day, but the not cool thing is that it's now been in review since Dec 3.